# Deepcopy pandas DataFrame containing python objects (such as lists)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, memory-management

Need help understanding variable assignment, pointers, ...

The following is reproducible.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'listData': [
        ['c', 'f', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'b'], 
        [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]
    ]})

df['listDataSort'] = df['listData']
```

gives:

```
             listData        listDataSort
0  [c, f, d, a, e, b]  [c, f, d, a, e, b]
1     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]
```

If I only want to sort the lists in the `listDataSort` column, I might try:

```py
df['listDataSort'].apply(lambda l: l.sort())
df
```

However, that sorts the lists in both columns, in-place.

```
             listData        listDataSort
0  [a, b, c, d, e, f]  [a, b, c, d, e, f]
1     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I can fix this by instead doing:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'listData': [
        ['c', 'f', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'b'], 
        [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]
    ]})

df['listDataSort'] = df['listData'].apply(sorted)
```

giving:

```
             listData        listDataSort
0  [c, f, d, a, e, b]  [a, b, c, d, e, f]
1     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Assigning df to a different variable, say df2 still changes everything back to the original source list.  Furthermore, how do I create a new dataframe based on an existing dataframe so I can make changes to the new dataframe without making the same changes to the existing dataframe?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'listData': [
        ['c', 'f', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'b'], 
        [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]
    ]})

df2 = df
print('\ndf\n', df)
print('\ndf2\n', df2)

df2['listDataSort'] = df2['listData']
print('\ndf\n', df)
print('\ndf2\n', df2)

df2['listDataSort'].apply(lambda l: l.sort())
print('\ndf\n', df)
print('\ndf2\n', df2)
```

prints:

```
df
             listData
0  [c, f, d, a, e, b]
1     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]

df2
             listData
0  [c, f, d, a, e, b]
1     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]

df
             listData        listDataSort
0  [c, f, d, a, e, b]  [c, f, d, a, e, b]
1     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]

df2
             listData        listDataSort
0  [c, f, d, a, e, b]  [c, f, d, a, e, b]
1     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]

df
             listData        listDataSort
0  [a, b, c, d, e, f]  [a, b, c, d, e, f]
1     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

df2
             listData        listDataSort
0  [a, b, c, d, e, f]  [a, b, c, d, e, f]
1     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

also:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'listData': [
        ['c', 'f', 'd', 'a', 'e', 'b'], 
        [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]
    ]})
print('\ndf\n', df)

df3 = df
df3['listDataSort'] = df3['listData'].apply(sorted)
print('\ndf\n', df)
print('\ndf3\n', df3)
```

prints:

```
df
             listData
0  [c, f, d, a, e, b]
1     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]

df
             listData        listDataSort
0  [c, f, d, a, e, b]  [a, b, c, d, e, f]
1     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

df3
             listData        listDataSort
0  [c, f, d, a, e, b]  [a, b, c, d, e, f]
1     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run

```
df['listDataSort'] = df['listData']
```

All you do is copy the *references* of the lists to new columns. This means only a shallow copy is performed and both columns reference the same lists. So any change to one column will likely affect another.

You can use a list comprehension with `sorted` which returns a copy of the data. This should be the easiest option for you.

```
df['listDataSort'] = [sorted(x) for x in df['listDataSort']]
df

             listData        listDataSort
0  [c, f, d, a, e, b]  [a, b, c, d, e, f]
1     [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

Now, when it comes to the problem of making a copy of the entire DataFrame, things are a little more complicated. I would recommend `deepcopy`:

```
import copy
df2 = df.apply(copy.deepcopy)
```

Comment: from OP: `df['listDataSort'] = df['listData'].apply(sorted)` is nearly the same solution I had for the columns, not sure which one is faster, perhaps using `numpy.sort` would be faster still.  Thanks for pointing me to `deepcopy`.