# How to deep copy Pandas Dataframe which contains nested data structure?

Tags: python, pandas, nested, deep-copy

I have studied **shallow copy** and **deep copy**. I found that **`copy.deepcopy()`** works perfectly fine for most cases. Somehow, it doesn't work on the pandas dataframe which has nested data structures.

Please see the following examples and results, you will immediately know what I am talking about:

```
import pandas as pd 
import copy`

a = pd.Series([[1,2], 3], index=["a", "b"])
b = a.copy(deep=True)                       
print('-->CASE 1')
print('before: \n', a)
d[0][0]=3
print('after: \n', a, '\n\n')

c = pd.Series([[1,2], 3], index=["a", "b"])
d = c.copy(deep=True)                       
print('-->CASE 2')
print('before: \n', c)
d[0]=3
print('after: \n', c, '\n\n')

e = pd.Series([[1,2], 3], index=["a", "b"])
print('-->CASE 3')
f = copy.deepcopy(e)                         
print('before: \n', e)
f[0][0]=3
print('after: \n', e, '\n\n')

g = pd.Series([[1,2], 3], index=["a", "b"])
print('-->CASE 4')                            
h = copy.deepcopy(g)
print('before: \n', g)
h[0]=3
print('after: \n', g, '\n\n')
```

The results are like:

```
-->CASE 1
before: 
a    [1, 2]
b         3
dtype: object
after: 
a    [3, 2]
b         3
dtype: object 


-->CASE 2
before: 
a    [1, 2]
b         3
dtype: object
after: 
 a    [1, 2]
b         3
dtype: object 


-->CASE 3
before: 
a    [1, 2]
b         3
dtype: object
after: 
a    [3, 2]
b         3
dtype: object 


-->CASE 4
before: 
a    [1, 2]
b         3
dtype: object
after: 
a    [1, 2]
b         3
```

Apparently, neither `copy.deepcopy()` nor `df.copy(deep=True)` can truly perform deep copy when a dataframe contains nested data structures.

How to do a real **"DEEP COPY"** of the dataframe with nested data like the example cases?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031463/4909087) help? `df2 = df.apply(copy.deepcopy)`

Comment: @coldspeed It solved the issue. Thanks!!